# Mongoose nested sub/child document pre-save Hook wrong order

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

===== UPDATE 3 (Apr 4 2019) =========

I'm using  "mongoose": "^5.4.20"  (snipped to test the problem at the bottom)

I need to execute the pre-save of the nested children elements in turn BEFORE that of the parent.
This is my use-case:

```
bank                           // parent
  +---bank_account             // 1st level child
  |          +----trans        // 2nd level child
  |          +----trans
  +---bank_account
             +----trans
```

SCHEMAS

```
   // a bank have multiple accounts, total has the total amount of money available in the whole bank
   bank : {
            total    : {type:Number},
            accounts : [ {type : bank_account} ]
           }

    // a bank account has a balance calculated with all its transfers
    bank_account: {
                    balance   : {type:Number},
                    transfers : [ {type:trans} ]
                  }

    trans: {
            amount : {type:Number},  // always positive
            type   : {type:String, enum:["credit", "debit"]}        
           }
```

HOOKS

```
//Bank
   // sum all the accounts balance to have the total
    bank.schema.pre('save'. function(next)
     { 
      var self = this;
      self.total = 0;
     // calculate total iterating among all the accounts
      for(let a in self.accounts)
        {
          self.total += self.accounts[a].balance;
        }
      return next();
     })

 //Bank Account 
   // calculate the balance considering the transfers
    bank_account.pre('save'. function(next)
     { 
      var self = this;
      self.balance = 0;
      // calculate balance iterating among transfers
      for(let t in self.transfers)
        {
          var trans = self.transfers[t].balance;
          if(trans.type == "credit")
             { self.balance  += trans.amount; }
          else // debit
             { self.balance -= trans.amount;}
        }
      return next();
     })
```

When I do

```
bank.accounts[x].transfers.push(trans);
bank.save();
```

I expect that, after the `.save()`, `bank.total` would have the correct total, considering also the new transfer I'v just added. BUT it's not the case...  how could I make it work? The very dirty solution could be execute the `bank.save()` 2 times, but it's a very dirty solution..

[Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) v.5.4.21 says that:

> Subdocuments' pre('save') and pre('validate') middleware execute
>   before the top-level document's pre('save') but after the top-level
>   document's pre('validate') middleware. This is because validating
>   before save() is actually a piece of built-in middleware.

But it's real only when there are just 1st level children. In my case I have nested children, and the correct order is kept just among parent and (any level) children... as if all the level would be flattened.

I made **a snipped on [REPL](https://repl.it/@DanieleFani/Mongoose-nested-children-hook-order-presave) that shows the problem**